# Adding non executable jar in spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, dependency-injection, pom.xml

I have created a non executable jar and uploaded it on artifactory. This jar does not package the libs but only the compiled code.

I have another project which uses this jar and on running this application I get following error:

```
Field demoManager in com.demo.service.impl.SimpleDemoService required a bean of type 'com.demo.manager.impl.DemoManagerService' that could not be found.
```

for each @Autowired object in the non-executable jar and its referenced dependencies. I've added the non executable jar dependency as below:

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.demo</groupId>
      <artifactId>demo-library</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: https://spring.io/guides/gs/multi-module/ !? (your depending app must  declare/import the beans/(auto)config)

Comment: ...in the guide as simple as `@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = "com.example.multimodule")` .i.e. root package (of both modules)

Comment: Already tried this. Even after trying this it gives the same issue for dependencies included in non-executable jar.